# Gem dependency conflict between coffee-rails and rspec-rails

Tags: rubygems, dependencies, coffeescript, rspec-rails, rails-3-upgrade

I'm upgrading an app from rails 3.1.1 to rails 3.2. I had to update version of coffee-rails as well as rspec-rails to their latest versions to work with rails 3.2. However, they both seem to be incompatible with each other. When I run the bunder I get

```
  In Gemfile:
coffee-rails (~> 3.2.2) ruby depends on
  actionpack (= 3.2.0) ruby

rspec-rails (~> 2.8.1) ruby depends on
  actionpack (3.0.0)
```

However, on [rubygems for rspec-rails](http://rubygems.org/gems/rspec-rails), it clearly specifies the dependency to be `>= actionpack (3.0.0)`

Has anybody faced this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this recently just pasting in the Gemifile the asset group from a fresh new Rails 3.2 application:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
```

It's not a perfect way of doing it but you can remove your current Gemfile.lock and bundle the app as a new one. It sounds dirty in theory but it works just fine in practice. You can always see the differences with a git diff, supposing you're using it.

Comment: I think using coffee-rails 3.2.1 instead of 3.2.2 did the trick. I also did not have version specification of uglifier previously. Thanks so much!