# Error with installing rspec-rails and capybara gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, bundler

Brief Context:

My Gemfile looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

group :development do
    gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
    gem 'rspec-rails', '2.9.0'
end

gem 'therubyracer'

# group :production do
#   gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
# end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

group :test do
    # gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.0'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
```

On running bundle install in my app folder, i am getting following error:

```
$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Using rake (0.9.2.2) 
Using i18n (0.6.0) 
Using multi_json (1.3.5) 
Using activesupport (3.2.3) 
Using builder (3.0.0) 
Using activemodel (3.2.3) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using journey (1.0.3) 
Using rack (1.4.1) 
Using rack-cache (1.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.1) 
Using hike (1.2.1) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Using sprockets (2.1.3) 
Using actionpack (3.2.3) 
Using mime-types (1.18) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.10) 
Using mail (2.4.4) 
Using actionmailer (3.2.3) 
Using arel (3.0.2) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.33) 
Using activerecord (3.2.3) 
Using activeresource (3.2.3) 
Using bundler (1.1.3) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.3.1) 
Using execjs (1.3.2) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2) 
Using json (1.7.3) 
Using rdoc (3.12) 
Using thor (0.14.6) 
Using railties (3.2.3) 
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2) 

Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate A (https://rubygems.cachefly.net/gems/diff-lcs-1.1.3.gem)
An error occured while installing diff-lcs (1.1.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install diff-lcs -v '1.1.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

However, if I comment out *gem rspec-rails', '2.9.0'*, its installing smoothly. I think the problem is with the way gem is installing. Kindly help with what to do? If you need more information, do tell me.

Comment: May that be the same issue as here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410814/gem-dependency-conflict-between-coffee-rails-and-rspec-rails ?

Comment: It could have been, but it didn't turned out to be so. Thanks anyway. Problem solved. See the comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to install the diff-lcs before bundling again

```
gem install diff-lcs -v '1.1.3
bundle install
```

Comment: Hi All, I guess it finally boiled down to network issue. I run the same command with same Gemfile and it worked. To all my friends who might be facing such kind of error.. I would say try after 7-8 hrs.. I should work. Though, I am not sure of the reason why its so. Can anyone guess?

Answer (score 0):

Because of the nature of the SSL-specific error, you may want to consider switching to a non-secure connection to get the gems.  As suggested in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17044361), check your `Gemfile` for a line like:

```
source 'https://rubygem.org'
```

and change it to the non-https version:

```
source 'http://rubygem.org'
```