# Why bundler doesn't see customized gem source?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundler

First of all the thing is that I'm behind firewall so I can't use https://rubygems.org/

```
 $ bundle install rails
bundle install requires at least 0 argument: "bundle install".
git@gitdev  $ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake (10.0.4) 

Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A (https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/gems/i18n-0.6.1.gem)
An error occurred while installing i18n (0.6.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install i18n -v '0.6.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I thought that `bundler` uses `rubygems` so I looked at `rubygems` sources:

```
$ gem source
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***
http://rubygems.org/
```

before it was `https://rubygems.org`

This setup is using `RVM`. When using global ruby installation, by changing `gem` source, I was able to install rails. All ssl connection blocked by firewall especially github and aws. Non-ssl links works in my environment.

So question is why `bundler` doesn't see that `gems` has a non-ssl'ed source?

Comment: Is there a `~/.gemrc` on your machine?

Comment: answered bellow, it's in the `Gemfile` which bundler generated before I've changed a rubygems source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check you Gemfile, it must have a line specifying the source used by bundler:

```rb
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

This is the default source used by bundler.

Comment: lol that was so stupid from me. Thanks for figuring it out, I don't have much experience with ruby just trying to install gitlab application. :)